# How to implement an onDatePickerChanged when i have MyCustomClass extends DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I have a custom class called `DatePicker` who extends `DialogFragment` and implements `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`, but my problem is because y need to listen the `onDateChangeMethod` and the `DialogFragment` only have `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` and `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`.

How can I do that? I tried to implement `OnDateChangedListener` and override the `onDateChange` method but it did not work. Here is the code:

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, OnDateChangedListener {

    private OnDateSetListener _onDateSetListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        _onDateSetListener = (OnDateSetListener) activity;
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Date initialValue = null;
        String[] buttons = getArguments().getStringArray("buttons");

        Long initialValueLong = getArguments().getLong("initialValue");
        if (initialValue == null) {
            initialValue = new Date();
        }

        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(initialValueLong);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));


        return dialog;
    }

     @Override
     public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,
           int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
           _onDateSetListener.onDateSet(new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear,
               dayOfMonth).getTime(), getArguments().get("tag"));
     }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        // THIS METHOD NEVER CALLED

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the onDateSetListener that the dialog calls back to?

Comment: DatePickerDialog already implements OnDateChangedListener. You probably need a DatePiker,

Comment: How are you actually creating the dialog?

Comment: DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
      datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
        "datePicker");

Remember, DatePicker is my customClass, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just only need to get de DatePicker and set DatePicker.init method

> android.widget.DatePicker datePicker = dialog.getDatePicker();
>        datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
>            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
>                new OnDateChangedListener() {
>                    public void onDateChanged(android.widget.DatePicker view,
>                               int year, int month, int day) {
>                           _onDateSetListener.dateChange(new GregorianCalendar(
>                                   year, month, day).getTime(), getArguments()
>                                   .get("tag"));
>                       }
>                   });

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't declared an onDateSetListener in your class, and you're also casting the host activity to the wrong type.  The Dialog class itself should be the OnDateSetListener, and the host activity should be cast to something else.

Try to structure the class like this:

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
                                             DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    public static interface DatePickedListener
    {
        public void onDatePicked(int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay);
    }

    private DatePickedListener listener;        

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        // when the fragment is initially attached to the activity, cast the
        // activity to the callback interface type
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try
        {
            listener = (DatePickedListener) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + DatePickedListener.class.getName());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Bundle b = getArguments();

        int year = b.getInt("set_year");
        int month = b.getInt("set_month");
        int day = b.getInt("set_day");

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int setYear, int setMonth, int setDay)
    {
        // when the date is selected, send it to the activity via its callback interface method

        listener.onDatePicked(setYear, setMonth, setDay);
    }           
}
```

Comment: I have the onDateSetListener, I only forgot to put in the code, I will do now.